# readarray only taking first line from input file

Tags: bash

I have a pipeline to analyze some data and I wanted to add a short script that takes failed samples from a previous step and do something with them but I'm having an issue reading the input file in as an array. My input file and script are set up like this:

Input file (file name is prev_step.failed):

```
Samp_12405736
Samp_12405737
Samp_12405738
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t samples </local/path/to/data/prev_step.failed
for samp in $samples
do
    echo $samp
    # do something with $samp here
done
```

The issue I am having is that what I loop through $samples and print each sample only the first one (Samp_12405736) is printed.

Comment: `for samp in "${samples[@]}"`

Comment: You are doing something very wrong then. I just coped your example and with the changes it works fine. There is 1 other possibility. Your input file has **DOS** line endings (e.g. `"\r\n"`) -- that will cause the issue you see. Make sure your input file has Unix line ending `'\n'`. You can use `dos2unix /local/path/to/data/prev_step.failed` to convert.

Comment: fwiw, `samples` is an array; `${samples}` (without an index reference) is comparable to `${samples[0]}`, which is going to be the first entry in the array; as David's pointed out, to reference the entire array you want to use `${samples[@]}`

Comment: also, `typeset -p samples` will show you the entire structure/contents of the array (ie, this should should you 3 entries - one for each line from `prev_step.failed`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing an array as a simple scalar returns the first element.

```
$: samples=( a b c )

$: echo $samples
a
$: printf "%s\n" $samples
a

$: echo "${samples[@]}"
a b c 
$: printf "%s\n" "${samples[@]}"
a
b
c
```